# calculate event runtimes from timestamps and start/stop data

Tags: r, dataframe, events, timestamp, runtime

I'm new to coding and I am trying to calculate runtimes for different events but not sure how to do this in R, can someone point me in the right direction. I've added a screenshot of the dataset I'm working with below.

Here's what i've done so far:

```
RT_df = checkpoint_df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = eventType, values_from = timestamp)

duration(RT_df$eventName)
```

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQAPZ.png)

Comment: @jad apologies I hadn't noticed that, I've updated the post so it should be visible now.

Comment: can you add an example of what output you would like to get?

Comment: @jad I'm trying to show which event types dominate task runtimes. So the output I would like is the run time for each event which I could then plot the averages of if that makes sense?